# Conditional formatting with multiple conditions

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have to set a simple formatting in excel: colour cells if the value is = to another cell.

The question is that I would like to colour the cells if the value equal to A1 **or** B1 **or** B3

Is it possible to set it with only one rules or I have to set the same rules threen different times?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `OR()` function in your conditional formatting...

```
=OR( CELL=$A$1, CELL=$B$1, CELL=$C$1 ) = TRUE
```

etc

When you select the rule for your conditional formatting you shouldn't select the simple rule `Equal To`. You need to select `More Rules` and then `Use a formula` to determine which cells to format

--

Thanks to @User15 for the suggested clarification

Comment: One important point to add to the answer: When you select the rule for your conditional formatting you shouldn't select the simple rule `Equal To`. You need to select `More Rules` and then `Use a formula to determine which cells to format`

Comment: Good point... answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to colour the cells with only one rule, you can use logical OR() operator in conditional formatting

```
=OR(D1=A1,D1=B1,D1=B3)
```

here, D1 contains the value to be compared with A1, B1 and B3 cells value, if any one conditions met, you can set to change the colour of D1 to your liking.

Comment: One important point to add to the answer: When you select the rule for your conditional formatting you shouldn't select the simple rule `Equal To`. You need to select `More Rules` and then `Use a formula to determine which cells to format`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the OR Operator in your conditional formatting like below:

```
=IF(OR(A1 = B1,B1 =B3),"work”, "not work")
```

Hope this is helpful for you.